# ios Create new file and add to all target automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, addtarget

Currently, I have 2 target like this.

[image]

When I create some file, it only choose 1 for default like this. I have to choose all target manually.

[image]

I afraid that developers might make some mistakes and don't add to app store version. Is there any way to automatically select both target? Or at least, by default, App Store version should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [an Xcode plugin here](https://github.com/poboke/AllTargets) that precisely does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file and select all the targets. Xcode will automatically remember and select those targets when creating subsequent files.

[image: File -> New -> File -> Swift file]