# Is there a way to add a file to all Xcode target without manually selecting all target or using a plugin

Tags: xcode, ide

A minor issue that causes trouble to me many times is i forget to add files to all target when creating it. same thing happen with other developers that are working on the same project I searched and came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836002/ios-create-new-file-and-add-to-all-target-automatically) and found this [plugin](https://github.com/poboke/AllTargets) but the question was more then 2 years old.

Also found this in an answer somewhere

> Xcode remembers the selection you make in the dialog, so when you
>   select all targets once, it should have them all selected by default
>   when you add files the next time.

Doesn't seem to working for me. I want to know is there a way we can do this thing without manually selecting all the targets everytime when we add a new file to project.

Thanks

Comment: if you select it once and selection is not accordingly next time. Please raise a bug again Xcode.